# Stable sort and default vs custom three-way comparison

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

Why does the following code with the custom three-way comparison operator fail to compile? It does compile when replacing the custom three-way comparison operator with the default (commented out in the code below). I tested this using GCC 13.2 and Clang 18.1.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <compare>

struct A {

    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const A&) const {
        return std::strong_ordering::equivalent;
    };

    // std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const A&) const = default;

    int x;
};

int main () {
    std::vector<A> v = { {1}, {3}, {4}, {7}};
    std::ranges::stable_sort(v);
    return 0;
}
```

The error message includes `is_invocable_v<std::ranges::less &, A &, A &>' evaluated to false`, however `const bool x = A(1) < A(2)` does compile. See detailed compiler errors here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T5o7dG3Kq

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: Non-defaulted `<=>` doen't generate `==`, and `stable_sort` probably wants that (not sure if it actually uses it or just checks).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks! This is the solution. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat • Good insight!  The error message leaves a lot to be desired.  At one time in draft, the `operator<=>` would synthesize the `==` and `!=`, but that feature was pulled because (iirc) it couldn't be made generically performant.  Instead the standard used the user provided `operator==` for synthesizing the `operator!=`, and `operator<=>` only synthesizes `<` `>` `<=` `>=`.

Comment: I remember seeing duplicates about this, so I don't really want to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ranges::stable_sort` uses a specialization of `std::ranges::less` to compare objects.

[[range.cmp]#8](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.cmp#8):

> Constraints: T and U satisfy `totally_ordered_with`.

(See [[concept.totallyordered]](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.totallyordered#concept:totally_ordered_with))

Which, requires that `operator==` exists. While `operator<=>` implicitly generates `>=` and `<=` operators,

[[class.compare]#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.compare#default-4):

> If the *member-specification* does not explicitly declare any member or friend named `operator==`, an `==` operator function is declared implicitly for each three-way comparison operator function defined as defaulted [...]

In other words, only a defaulted `operator<=>` would implicitly generate `operator==`, which does not meet the requirement `totally_ordered_with`.

Declaring a `==` operator will suffice:

```
struct A {

    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const A&) const {
        return std::strong_ordering::equivalent;
    };

+   bool operator==(const A&) const {
+       return true;
+   }

    int x;
};
```

Comment: I do notice the problem is solved under the post comments.

Comment: This is a broken `==` though, comparing the same object must yield true. You could always return true to be consistent with `<=>`.

Comment: Edited the answer to return true in `==`